# Переставить по месту четные элементы в начало в одномерном массиве

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, любой-язык

Не могу понять алгоритм перестановки элементов в этой задаче:

> Дан массив. Без использования дополнительного массива переставить элементы так, чтобы вначале шли все элементы под четными исходными индексами, затем - нечетными.
>
> Пример:
> Исходный массив 3 5 1 6 0 4 6
> Выход 3 1 0 6 5 6 4*

Приведите пожалуйста пример на каком-нибудь языке. Или словесное описание алгоритма.

Comment: на самом деле тут много зависит от многого. Например можно схитрить и вместо массива использовать список. Можно строки использовать. Можно в каком-нибудь C# использовать LINQ или java streams. А можно и циклами. Так что зависит от языка и от способа

Comment: Индексация, значит, с `0`.

Comment: А относительный порядок элементов сохранять требуется? В условии этого не сказано, а в примере он сохранен. То есть `5136645` - это будет правильным ответом или нет?

Comment: Относительный порядок элементов требуется сохранить. Как в примере.

Comment: @AnT допустим относительный порядок не важен, тогда почему `5136645` должно быть правильным ответом ?? ведь первый элемент 5 под нечётным индексом 1, что уже не верно ... или вы подразумевали индексацию с 1 ?

Comment: @ampawd Я просто опечатался. Имелось в виду `0136645`

Answer (score 6):

Очевидный "лобовой" алгоритм - проходим по элементам с четными индексами `s` и при помощи последовательного применения обмена элемента массива с соседом слева "загоняем" этот элемент в его правильное положение `d`.

Например, для `3 5 1 6 0 4 6`:

s = 0, d = 0: элемент [0] (3) и так на месте
s = 2, d = 1: элемент [2] (1) должен попасть на место [1]. Обмениваем [1]-[2]
`3 1 5 6 0 4 6`
s = 4, d = 2: элемент [4] (0) должен попасть на место [2]. Обмениваем [4]-[3], [3]-[2]
`3 1 0 5 6 4 6`
s = 6, d = 3: элемент [6] (6) должен попасть на место [3]. Обмениваем [6]-[5], [5]-[4], [4]-[3]
`3 1 0 6 5 6 4`

Каждая последовательноcть обменов - это на самом деле циклический сдвиг вправо для подмассива [d, s], который можно реализовать несколько более эффективно, чем вышеописанная последовательность обменов.

В С++, например, можно воспользоваться готовой функцией `std::rotate`, хотя сдвиг на 1 элемент в любом случае реализуется тривиально

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int a[] = { 3, 5, 1, 6, 0, 4, 6 };
  size_t N = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

  std::copy_n(std::begin(a), N, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  for (std::size_t s = 0, d = 0; s < N; s += 2, ++d)
    std::rotate(a + d, a + s, a + s + 1);

  std::copy_n(std::begin(a), N, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: можно упомянуть, что это квадратичный алгоритм (`O(n**2)` обменов). Оптимально, можно за `O(n)` обменов элементы переставить.

Comment: @jfs: Возможно.  Если бы разрешили использовать дополнительный булевский массив, то задача решалась бы без проблем путем "жонглирования" значениями по циклам перестановки. А вот как без дополнительного массива... Наверное можно.

Comment: линейная последовательность обменов однозначно существует ([`number_of_swaps()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989341/4279)). Вопрос может быть только, возможно ли эту последовательность в O(1) памяти закодировать (не знаю).

Answer (score 0):

для разнообразия и лучшего понимания, приведу реализацию лобового алгоритма из ответа @Ant  но без использования `std::rotate`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void f(std::vector<int>& a)
{  
    std::vector<int>::size_type N = a.size();
    for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < N; i += 2, ++k)
    {
        for (int j = i; j > k; --j)
        {
            std::swap(a[j], a[j-1]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {3, 5, 1, 6, 0, 4, 6};     
    f(a);    
    std::copy_n(std::begin(a), a.size(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector<int> b = { 7, 8, 3, 0, 1, 4, 5, 11 }; 
    f(b);    
    std::copy_n(std::begin(b), b.size(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```